# How to share and point on a place on Google map?

Tags: google-maps

I have a website and I am going to use google map to show where am I, I want to point on that place.

[Something like this.](http://farsi.balaghah.net/sites/all/themes/nahjFarsi/image/fp/map.jpg)

How can I do it and then share it public?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ad a Placemark (point on) a map just by these steps:

1-Getting the *latitude and longitude* by clicking on the point that you want to put a marker on that place, and select **what's here?** the latitude and longitude  will shows on left top side of website.

2-Search that latitude and longitude by following format:

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=35.128061,-106.535561&ll=35.126517,-106.535131&z=17

TO

> http://maps.google.com/maps?q=latitude-and-longitude

Answer (score 1):

Kermani suggested searching for the coordinates and then sending the link. It can (now?) be done a bit more elegantly:

1. Long Click the point on the map
2. An info box opens on the top left below the search field mentioning the coordinates.
3. Copy paste the coordiantes into the search box and search. A map with a point marker will appear.
4. Click opn the gear symbol on the bottom right next to the street view figure and chose "Share or Embed Map"
5. Copy and share the long or short version URL provided.